# Наполнить столбец при условии совпадения с другим значениями

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У нас есть два массива, в одном, Df1, товары и их номера.

| Description | PN |
| --- | --- |
| SHAFT | 333 |
| ENGINE | 444 |
| ACTUATOR | 555 |

В другом, Df2, на некоторые из номеров нам дали цену:

| PN | P |
| --- | --- |
| 333 | 100 |
| 444 | 200 |

Хотим добавить значения столбца "Р" напротив столбца "PN".

```
list= []
for h in df1['PN']:
        for u in zip(df2['PN'], df2['P']):
             if h==u[0]:
                 list.append(u)
a = len(df1['PN'])
b = len(list)
c = a - b
df1['P'] = list(list[1]).extend(['']*c)
```

то есть мы, если значение из столбца P равно значению столбцу PN, сделали список кортежей из совпадающих значений,
ввели новый столбец и выравняли его с длиной массива Дф1.
Остаётся только ввести эти совпадающие значения из списка кортежей в новый столбец,

```
for h in list[0]:
    for u in df1['PN']:
        for j in list[1]:
            if h==u:
                df1['P'].append(j)
```

Объект нового столбца - серия, но машина выдаёт ошибку на строку с аппэнд, что int ne iterable. Как можно доставить значения из того списка кортежей в тот столбец? спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
res = df1.merge(df2, how="left")
```

результат:

```
In [12]: res
Out[12]:
  Description   PN      P
0       SHAFT  333  100.0
1      ENGINE  444  200.0
2    ACTUATOR  555    NaN
```

PS по умолчанию `DataFrame.merge(other)` объединяет фреймы по столбцам с совпадающими наименованиями.

Comment: пытаюсь повторить опыт: два массива из экселя, в каждом есть столбец "PN", где есть частичное совпадение.  ```` fourth = first.join(third.set_index('PN'), on = 'PN') ```` это, если с Join. Получаю вывод, что KeyError: "None of ['PN'] are in the columns", хотя именно с таким названием есть столбцы в обоих массивах. Если через Merge, то вывод, MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False. Если установить при том left_on= 'PN', то вывод TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: @Fareed, советую открыть новый вопрос с __воспроизводимым__ примером данных)

Answer (score 3):

Если вам надо объединить два дата фрейма, то почему не использовать метод `join`. Пример из [документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pn': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3', 'K4', 'K5'],
                   'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']})
other = pd.DataFrame({'pn': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2'],
                      'p': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']})
df.join(other.set_index('pn'), on='pn')

'''

   pn   A    p
0  K0  A0   B0
1  K1  A1   B1
2  K2  A2   B2
3  K3  A3  NaN
4  K4  A4  NaN
5  K5  A5  NaN
```